# How do I target the parent of dynamically added HTML elements with a click listener, if my click listener does not bubble up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a function like so, which takes data from an AJAX and renders it to the DOM.

```
function populateProfile(arr) {
let items = ``;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const { title, sport, members, membersLimit, description, _id } = arr[i];
    const { lat, long } = arr[i].location;

    items = items.concat(`
        <div id="${_id}" class="post-item">
            <div class="post-item-list">
                <ul>
                    <li><h4>${title}<h4></li>
                    <li>Sport: ${sport}</li>
                    <li>Max players: ${membersLimit}</li>
                    <li>Current players: ${members}</li>
                    <li> Description: <p>${description}</p></li>
                    <li>${lat},${long}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    `);
}
$('#ownPosts').append(items);
}
```

For this function I have assigned an id to the very first div, which is a container for all the elements.

I have the following function, which is click event listener, which should grab the id of the clicked div and pass it to viewSinglePost, which is an AJAX request to return data for a single post and render it to the DOM as a modal.

```
function popPost() {
$('#ownPosts').on('click', '.post-item', (event) => {
    const singlePost = event.target.id
    viewSinglePost(singlePost);
});
}
```

Currently, popPost() will only trigger when clicking on ONLY the div with the class "post-item". If I click the ul or li or any child elements of the div.post-item, it will not trigger even though they are within the div.

So, I'm asking how can I get the click listener to register that clicking any of div.post-item's child elements, grandchild elements, etc... will treat it like it clicked div.post-item?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: can you descrive what is **#ownPosts**? Thanks

Comment: Sorry my mistake I mistyped the first function. #ownPosts is a div meant to hold the appended items.

Comment: @Kaleidics Please add the html/frontend code or screenshot so we have a proper idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are looking for the id of parent div with class **post-item**.

If that is your issue you can change this line:

```
const singlePost = event.target.id
```

with:

```
const singlePost = $(event.target).closest('div.post-item').attr('id')
```

or, in plain js:

```
const singlePost = event.target.closest('div.post-item').id;
```

Where:

> [jQuery.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/): , get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

The snippet:

```js
populateProfile([{"title": 1, "sport": 1, "members":1, "membersLimit":1, "description":1, "_id":1,
    "location": {"lat": 1, "long": 1}},
    {"title":2, "sport":2, "members":2, "membersLimit":2, "description":2, "_id":2,
    "location": {"lat": 2, "long": 2}}]);
$('#ownPosts').on('click', '.post-item', function(event) {
    const singlePost = $(event.target).closest('div.post-item').attr('id');
    console.log('---> ' + singlePost);
    //viewSinglePost(singlePost);
});


function populateProfile(arr) {
    let items = ``;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const { title, sport, members, membersLimit, description, _id } = arr[i];
        const { lat, long } = arr[i].location;

        items = items.concat(`
    <div id="${_id}" class="post-item">
                <div class="post-item-list">
                <ul>
                <li><h4>${title}<h4></li>
                <li>Sport: ${sport}</li>
        <li>Max players: ${membersLimit}</li>
        <li>Current players: ${members}</li>
        <li> Description: <p>${description}</p></li>
        <li>${lat},${long}</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
`);
    }
    $('#ownPosts').append(items);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="ownPosts"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the right approach to show a post. You'll end up listening to more clicks than you may want. A few examples:

- Somewhere deep in your lists, you have a "copy to clipboard" button
- Or a clickable anchor

You don't want to deal with those items clicks here (i.e. filter them out), and they don't want to be slowed down by your show-post related feature, if they happen to bubble-up. This is not a good orientation, performance-wise.

Next to the `h4` title of each post, you could have a button responsible for showing the post details (I guess `viewSinglePost()` provides this feature). Then, you would place a listener on this/those buttons (one listener for all posts lists buttons), and know for sure what is intended by the end-user when a click happens there.

Comment: You make a very good point. I think I will implement this solution later. But, for now it's easier to click the whole div while I'm still working on some other things.